# Can you think of a way to replace "high time" in the sentence, "It's high time I took a shower"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

"High time" is too formal for the voice I'm using in this work.

Comment: "High time" isn't particularly formal (certainly in UK), I'd consider it colloquial besides expressions like "overdue" or "past time". So I guess you want a very informal term? Maybe focus on how much you stink?

Comment: There are at least two meanings. (1) It has been days (say) since I showered. // (2) Enough of this morning's busyness! I'm going for a shower **now**.

Comment: "Maybe focus on how much you stink?" wow, that escalated quickly, Stuart. (It's a very good idea, thanks man.)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's about time** (idiom)

> *Informal* —Used to say often in an annoyed way that something should have happened sooner
>
> *It's about time you got here. I've been waiting for over an hour!*
>
> *"They're getting married." "Well, it's about time!* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it%27s%20about%20time)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go colloquial, perhaps "I really need a shower" would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

"High time" in this context seems more like a pun than formality.

I suggest

> I **badly** need a shower.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/badly) has

> **badly**
> <sub>ADVERB</sub>
>
> **2.1** Very much or intensely.

Answer (score 0):

*past due*

> Okay, so Anderson has been rising for a while now. Maybe **it’s past
> due that I included him in my weekly column here**. ([New Arena](https://newarena.com/nfl/week-in-rewind-what-we-learned-from-week-12-in-the-nfl/))
>
> I love lolcats, so **it's past due that I made my own featuring our
> very own Tilly**. ([blog](http://www.outrageousfortune.net/2012/02/wordless-wednesday-o-hai-i-can-has-lap.html))

Answer (score 0):

A simple sentence may convey almost the same:

- I should have taken a shower **by now**.